# Build a dynamic query with Hibernate (no Criteria API)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following method:

```java
public List<Parcel> filter(ParcelFilterParameters pfp) {
    try (var session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
        var baseQuery = "from Parcel ";
        var filters = new ArrayList<String>();

        pfp.getCustomerId().ifPresent(e -> filters.add(" owner.id = :ownerId "));
        pfp.getCategoryId().ifPresent(e -> filters.add(" category.id = :categoryId "));


        if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
            baseQuery = baseQuery + " where " + String.join(" and ", filters);
        }

        Query<Parcel> query = session.createQuery(baseQuery, Parcel.class);

        pfp.getCustomerId().ifPresent(e -> query.setParameter("ownerId", e));
        pfp.getCategoryId().ifPresent(e -> query.setParameter("categoryId", e));
        return query.list();
    }
}
```

This is the ParcelFilterParameters class:

```java
public class ParcelFilterParameters {
    private Optional<Integer> customerId;
    private Optional<Integer> categoryId;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Although weird looking, it does work, but this repeats for a few other entities so I was wondering if I can make it more generic in some way (without using the Criteria API)? Or at least skip the second batch of `ifPresent(e -> ...`s?

Comment: Why can't you use the Criteria API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid `the second batch of ifPresent` you can use map to hold all query parameters:

```java
List<String> filters = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

pfp.getCustomerId().ifPresent(e -> {
    filters.add(" owner.id = :ownerId ");
    params.put("ownerId", e);
});
pfp.getCategoryId().ifPresent(e -> {
    filters.add(" category.id = :categoryId ");
    params.put("categoryId", e);
});
```

and apply them all in single method call:

```java
Query<Parcel> query = session.createQuery(baseQuery, Parcel.class);
query.setProperties(params);
return query.list();
```

Comment: Didn't know you could pass a map to the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Although you asked for no Criteria API usage consider using `org.hibernate.criterion.Example`. It scales well with a growing number of entities. The example introspects every field that is not null and will build your `where`-block from that.

First in the `ParcelFilterParameters` we should remove the `Optioals` from the fields since `Example` works fine with null-values. Then we build a `Parcel`-object from the
`ParcelFilterParameters` and create an `Example` from that. The `Example` can be added as an `Criterion` to the query.

```
public List<Parcel> filter(ParcelFilterParameters pfp) {
    try (var session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
        // Build example Parcel from ParcelFilterParameters
        Parcel parcel = new Parcel();
        // initialize customer/owner and category ...
        parcel.getOwner().setId(pfp.getCustomerId());
        parcel.getCategory().setId(pfp.getCategoryId());

        return session.createCriteria(Parcel.class)
                      .add(Example.create(parcel))
                      .list();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know about `Example`. Thank you.